# What could be the problem with this query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a query like this in Postgres:

```
select sum("ATD_AMOUNT") AS CREDIT_SUM, 0 AS DEBIT_SUM,"ATD_ACCOUNT_MST_ID","AAD_OPEN_AMOUNT","AAM_ACCOUNT_NAME", "AAM_ACCOUNT_CODE" ,"AAD_YEAR_ID" 
from db_accounts."ACC_TRANSACTION_DET" 
left outer join db_accounts."ACC_TRANSACTION_MST" ON "ATD_TRANSACTION_MST_ID"=    "ATM_TRANSACTION_MST_ID"
left outer join db_accounts."ACC_ACCOUNT_MST" ON "ATD_ACCOUNT_MST_ID"="AAM_ACCOUNT_MST_ID" 
left outer join db_accounts."ACC_ACCOUNT_DET" on "AAM_ACCOUNT_MST_ID"  = "AAD_ACCOUNT_MST_ID" and "AAD_YEAR_ID"=(select "AAY_YEAR_ID" from db_accounts."ACC_ACCOUNT_YEAR" where "AAY_IS_CURRENT_YEAR"=true)
where "ATM_TRANSACTION_DATE"<= $1 and "ATM_TRANSACTION_DATE">=(select "AAY_START_DATE" from db_accounts."ACC_ACCOUNT_YEAR" where "AAY_IS_CURRENT_YEAR"=true)
and "ATM_ON_REVERSE_PARENT_TRANSACTION_ID" is null and "ATM_IS_CANCELLED"=false
    and  "AAM_DEL_FLAG" =false
AND "ATD_CREDIT_DEBIT_TRANSACTION" = 'CREDIT'
GROUP BY "ATD_ACCOUNT_MST_ID","AAD_OPEN_AMOUNT","AAM_ACCOUNT_NAME", "AAM_ACCOUNT_CODE","AAD_YEAR_ID
```

Here the db_accounts."ACC_TRANSACTION_DET" contains some 50 lakh records also  db_accounts."ACC_TRANSACTION_MST" has 60000 records

Now my problem is when i run this query with same database in my system i get a result but when i try in other system it does not work?

Also what i have noticed is if any one of the below conditions are removed it displays a result

```
"ATM_TRANSACTION_DATE"<= $1 //field in db_accounts."ACC_TRANSACTION_MST" table

"ATM_TRANSACTION_DATE">=(select "AAY_START_DATE" from db_accounts."ACC_ACCOUNT_YEAR" where "AAY_IS_CURRENT_YEAR"=true) //field in db_accounts."ACC_TRANSACTION_MST" table

"ATD_CREDIT_DEBIT_TRANSACTION" = 'CREDIT' //field in db_accounts."ACC_TRANSACTION_DET" table
```

Comment: when you say "same database" do you mean both computers query the same database server, or did you copy over the database contents to a PostgreSQL instance running on your computer?

Comment: No its two different servers i took a back up from the other system and restored it in mine.It works fine in my system.Could this be because there is lot of data in the tables?

Comment: what does explain analyze have to say about the query? what indexes are available? are you sure you need the left joins, and that inner joins couldn't be used instead?

Comment: There are no indexes on the any tables.Only primary keys for each of them and a foreign reference to the DET table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reformatted your query with [www.prettysql.net](http://www.prettysql.net):

```
SELECT
 sum("ATD_AMOUNT") AS CREDIT_SUM,
 0 AS DEBIT_SUM,
 "ATD_ACCOUNT_MST_ID",
 "AAD_OPEN_AMOUNT",
 "AAM_ACCOUNT_NAME",
 "AAM_ACCOUNT_CODE",
 "AAD_YEAR_ID"
FROM
 db_accounts."ACC_TRANSACTION_DET" LEFT OUTER JOIN db_accounts."ACC_TRANSACTION_MST"
 ON
   "ATD_TRANSACTION_MST_ID"=
   "ATM_TRANSACTION_MST_ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN db_accounts."ACC_ACCOUNT_MST" ON "ATD_ACCOUNT_MST_ID" = "AAM_ACCOUNT_MST_ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN db_accounts."ACC_ACCOUNT_DET" ON
    "AAM_ACCOUNT_MST_ID" = "AAD_ACCOUNT_MST_ID"
  AND
   "AAD_YEAR_ID"=
   (
    SELECT "AAY_YEAR_ID"
    FROM db_accounts."ACC_ACCOUNT_YEAR"
    WHERE "AAY_IS_CURRENT_YEAR"=true
   )
WHERE
  "ATM_TRANSACTION_DATE"<=$1
 AND
  "ATM_TRANSACTION_DATE">=
  (
   SELECT "AAY_START_DATE"
   FROM db_accounts."ACC_ACCOUNT_YEAR"
   WHERE "AAY_IS_CURRENT_YEAR"=true
  )
 AND
  "ATM_ON_REVERSE_PARENT_TRANSACTION_ID" is null
 AND
  "ATM_IS_CANCELLED"=false
 AND
  "AAM_DEL_FLAG"=false
 AND
  "ATD_CREDIT_DEBIT_TRANSACTION"='CREDIT'
GROUP BY "ATD_ACCOUNT_MST_ID","AAD_OPEN_AMOUNT","AAM_ACCOUNT_NAME","AAM_ACCOUNT_CODE","AAD_YEAR_ID
```

It looks like you have a where clause in your query which contains $1, the pattern used in Postgresql for parameter passing.

Try replacing it with something like '2011-05-25'::date, and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting.....                                      Yes this part of code is taken from a function where parameters are passed.I found out that the problem occured in this part.Instead of $1 i passed '2011-05-01 00:00:00' which is the timestamp format in the table

Comment: If you replace $1 with a specific date, do you get the same results on both database servers?

Comment: As i have explained earlier this query runs fine in my system  and gives the expected result but just keeps on executing in the other system and doesn't give a result
(Same data in both system's and '2011-05-01 00:00:00' given instead of $1)

Comment: OK, then you should check out the DateStyle parameter configured in your Postgresql engines: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE